# Login dialog from home and authenticate homepage - ASP.Net MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Relatively new to asp .net using mvc/razor. I have a home page, which to start with is not authenticated. Now i have a button, which pops up a partial view in a dialog box (jqueryui) and asks for username password and pass int onto the AccountController. All is good till the point until the authentication takes place, now how do i notify my home page that we are authenticated or not? I am trying the redirect method, but not getting quite where to go from there. I don't want to reload the page again, so i am guessing i should be avoiding a redirect, any better way to do this?

Home.cshtml

```
dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 260,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function () {
                    $("#LogOnForm").submit();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

.
.
.

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Login to your account">
    @RenderPage("../Account/Login.cshtml")
</div>
```

.
.
.

```
$("#login").button().on("click", function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        });
```

controller.cshtml

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && MySqlWebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            //return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion redirect is not a bad solution here. I assume that most of your controllers/actions have Authorize attribute on them so when user successfully logs in he should be redirected to the required page.

Also i noticed that in case the login failed you redirect a user to a Home/Index - why don't you leave the user on the same login page and display him an error message?

Another solution could be submitting a form through ajax. Then you should modify your login action so it return an error (lets say 401 - unauthorized) if login failed and 200 - Ok if the login was successful (also assuming that you are using authentication cookie you should pass it here). Then you will have to monitor ajax complete event and check what response status are you getting. If you get a 401, display an error message in your dialog window, if you get 200, means login was successful - if you using form authentication cookie store it for future use and simply close a dialog form. From this point all the request are going to include this authentication cookie so all the request are going to pass the Authorization.

Comment: Ajax seems a good solution. So i return 200/401 from the controller and handle it in my home using ajax. Can you point me a link where i can refer for the ajax code for this. Again i am new to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

well you can Add a User Name label on your Home Page on which as an identifier. If a user is anonymous the label will display Hello Anonymous User and if the user gets authenticate you can simply display the user name along with Hello keyword, and by accessing the label you can identify the user is authenticated or not.

Also I believe after authentication there is a token generated which can also serve the purpose but if you just need to display or identify via HomePage display you can follow the above procedure.

For one of my project this serves the purpose for me

```
Hello, <asp:LoginName runat="server" /> !
```